# Is it okay to override pressesBegan() to minimize a fullscreen AVPlayer in tvOS?

Tags: ios, tvos

A part of my tvOS App UI is a minimized (400px width) `AVPlayer` and a button that sets that resizes the `AVPlayer` to fullscreen view by setting its frame to the window boundaries:

`playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)`.

I was not able to add a 'close fullscreen' button to the fullscreen avplayer (that would be the best solution) that's why I'm overriding the `pressesBegan()`-method with:

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?)
    {
        guard presses.first?.type == UIPressType.Menu else
        {
            super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
            return
        }

        // If not minimized, minimize it
        if playerController.view.frame.size.width != 400
        {
            playerController.view.frame = minimizedVideoBounds
        }
    }
```

**The question**

Is this a possible, safe and clean why to achieve my UX goal or is a a dirty hack that should be avoided at all costs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: No it's not. I got weird side effects. I think we should use the `AVPlayer` or the `AVPlayerController` as full screen element and we should avoid subclassing this stuff.

If somebody is smart enough to handle this: Please tell me how.